# Pandas Combining data in two excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have two excel

Excel 1

```
files   language    blank   comment code
15       C++            66  35      354
1       C/C++ Header    3   7        4
```

Excel 2

```
files   language    blank   comment code
16       C++           33   35      354
1       C/C++ Header    3   7        4
1       Python          1   1        1
```

Trying to get combined excel

```
files   language    blank   comment code
31       C++           99   70      708
2       C/C++ Header    6   14       8
1       Python          1   1        1
```

Any tips in pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum` by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('language', as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
       language  files  blank  comment  code
0           C++     31     99       70   708
1  C/C++ Header      2      6       14     8
2        Python      1      1        1     1
```

If order of columns is important add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df=pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('language',as_index=False).sum().reindex(columns=df1.columns)
print (df)
   files      language  blank  comment  code
0     31           C++     99       70   708
1      2  C/C++ Header      6       14     8
2      1        Python      1        1     1
```

Comment: You solved two thing in one even I wanted to change the order

Answer (score 0):

You can use

---

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner')
```

---

to merge

this is the easiest way to merge two or more DataFrames.
For more information read the Pandas documentations.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/